# I can not send a variable to a twig template

Tags: forms, symfony

I dont know why not can show a variable, I read the manual and I searched in many websites, but I have no idea what I'm doing wrong...

I have a classType (there is not from a entity), the class form have 3 combobox and a textbox, when I submit the form, another template (show2.html.twig) render the new form where I want show the textbox value... I speend many time and a have 0 result ;)

When I see the Symfony profiler, I can see the values of the form in the "Request POST Parameters" section, but I'cant catch it and show it in the twig template...

that is the code wath dont work for my

```
$this->get('request')->request->get('campo', 'can not show it ¬¬')
```

in the template dont show the "campo" value, just "can not show it ¬¬"

this is my classType

```
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {

        $builder->add('Pais', 'entity', array(
                    'class' => 'UnadeniZonaBundle:Pais',
                    'property' => 'paisnomb',
                ))
                ->add('Provincia', 'entity', array(
                    'class' => 'UnadeniZonaBundle:Provincia',
                    'property' => 'provnomb',
                ))
                ->add('Ciudad', 'entity', array(
                    'class' => 'UnadeniZonaBundle:Ciudad',
                    'property' => 'ciudnomb',
                ))
                ->add('Campo', 'text', array(
                        'label'  => 'campo',));
    }

    public function getName() {
        return 'ciudad2';
    }

    }
```

My controller...

```
    public function newAction(Request $request) {

        $form = $this->createForm(new Ciudad2Type());

        return $this->render('UnadeniZonaBundle:Ciudad2:new.html.twig', array(
                    'form' => $form->createView(),
            'mensaje' => 'test'
        ));
    }

    public function showAction(Request $request) {

        if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {

            return $this->render('UnadeniZonaBundle:Ciudad2:show2.html.twig', array(
                        'mensaje' => $this->get('request')->request->get('campo', 'can not show it ¬¬')
            ));
        }
    }
```

this the templates 
(new.html.twig)

```
    {% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

    {% block content -%}
    <form action="{{ path('ciudad2_show') }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
    {{ form_widget(form) }}

    <input type="submit" />

    {{ mensaje }}
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

(Show2.html.twig)

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

{% block content -%}

{{ mensaje }}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try this :

```
$postData = $request->request->get('ciudad2');
$targetValue = $postData['Campo'];

return $this->render('UnadeniZonaBundle:Ciudad2:show2.html.twig', array(
                    'mensaje' => $targetValue)
        ));
```

Comment: sounds good, I'll be at work 5 hours more, I will try and I will answeryou later
Thanks!

Comment: I love you!! 
ejemm...

it works fine, Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

It's a typo issue. Change `campo` to `Campo` in your controller.

```
if ($this->getRequest()->isMethod('POST')) {
  $request = $this->getRequest->request;
  $campo = $request->get('Campo', 'cannot show it.', true);
  return $this->render('UnadeniZonaBundle:Ciudad2:show2.html.twig', array(
                    'mensaje' => $campo
        ));
}
```

Comment: still not work :(

I try whit
'mensaje' => $request->request->get('Campo') but no working whit that

Comment: @user3439745 I updated my solution to get the deeper item from your request, too. Hopefully this works